# how to swap random enemies using random object?

Tags: java

how to swap random enemies? I was able to get the random x and y position but the problem is that some enemies are swapping on  top of each other. how can I edit below code?

```
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        //x, y
        enemy e = new enemy(r.nextInt(GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH), r.nextInt(GamePanel.WINDOW_HEIGHT));
        enemiesStore.add(e);
    }
```

Comment: just add `while(no enemy at x and y) x = random, y = random;`?

Comment: i did though about that but I feel like there is a simple solution. which doesnt use loops

Comment: Is there a reason not to use loops? It is the only way to solve your problem when randomly choosing positions.

Comment: Well, consider your option space. If you have objects, and you randomly assign certain properties to those objects ... loops are a simple way to ensure you do not end up with the "same" value on different objects. The only other option is that you "limit" the random generator more and more; basically by preventing it to pick random values that were already used during one "round". Long story short: nothing is complicated, if you spent enough time thinking about the underlying concepts.

Comment: i dont want to use loop bc what if i have 1000 enemies

Comment: Another way would be to generate a complete list of all possible positions `List<Position> positions`, then shuffle the list using `Collections.shuffle(positions, r)`.  Use the first `n` elements of the list to place `n` enemies.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
int y;int x;
ArrayList<String> listXY=new ArrayList();
Random r = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    x=r.nextInt(GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH);
    y=r.nextInt(GamePanel.WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    if(!listXY.contains(x+","+y))
    {
        enemy e = new enemy(x, y);
        listXY.add(x+","+y);
        enemiesStore.add(e);
    }
    else
    {
        i--;
    }
}
```

But it have a problem: If the random never get a propper position it can be an infinite loop.

**EDIT:** Another way to do the same would be the next one:
You can do a list of possible positions, and then choose them randomly and delete them from the list when picked.